# Как слать уведомления из фонового процесса?

Tags: android

Работает у меня в AsyncTask, в методе doInBackground() код. Принимает GET-запрос, разбирает JSON.

Когда я закрываю приложение - в кэше процесс приложения сохраняется. Этот тот самый поток?

Каким образом я могу, подобно мессенджерам например, выводить уведомление в шапке телефона из фонового потока?

UPD: Нашел "Notification", кажется это как раз то. Однако, буду благодарен любым советам по построению такого приложения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notification, да, это именно то, по поводу AsyncTask, по моему процесс сохраняется в том же потоке, но для операций, которые выполняють при закрытом приложении, лучше использовать сервисы, они дают гарантии, что процесс будет выполнен, если он не закрыт системой из-за нехвати ОЗУ.